# How to do sax parsing in android by referencing parent node

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am looking for sax parsing in android.I have got too many examples when searching, but none of that meets my requirements, So here I am posting XML structure that I have and my requirements.

`<vehicle_appname version="1.0">`

```
<vehicle_selection>

<vehicle_selection_option name="car">

<vehicle_issues>
<vehicle_item id="1" vehicle_filename="honda" vehicle_fileurl="honda13" icon_image="hodaFeb13.png" vehicle_heading="1.png" chapter_count="45"/>
<vehicle_item id="2" vehicle_filename="benz" vehicle_fileurl="Woman_feb13" icon_image="benzfeb13.png" vehicle_heading="1.png" chapter_count="6"/>
</vehicle_issues>

</vehicle_selection_option>

<vehicle_selection_option name="jeep">

<vehicle_issues>
<vehicle_item id="1" vehicle_filename="mahindra" vehicle_fileurl="mahindra" icon_image="mahindra_Feb13.png" vehicle_heading="1.png" chapter_count="45"/>

</vehicle_issues>


</vehicle_selection_option>

</vehicle_selection>
</vehicle_appname>
```

Here vehicle_selection_option name is an header tag and the vehicle_item tag contains contents for that header,there can be single or more contents tags.
My requirements :

1. I want to parse this xml. I know that XML sax parsing is easy,but here I have nested xml file.So the values in vehicle tag must be appropriate to its header(vehicle_selection_option  tag).
2. I want to show this contents in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `startElement` and `endElement` is all you need. In fact `startElement` will notify beginning of an element. Meanwhile `endElement` will notify the end of an element. So you can keep track when the  `vehicle_selection_option` open and close

Something like this: check for typo

```
boolean newCar = false;
@override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
   if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("vehicle_selection_option"))
      newCar = true;
 }

@override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
   if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("vehicle_selection_option"))
      newCar = false;
 }
```

Comment: can you help me with example?

Answer (score 0):

Check the localValue(parameter of startElement) with vlaue"vehicle_selection_option" on startElement method and create the object of Vechile(which you are using for store the vehicle information) and also check same string in endElement mothod and add this object to collection(i.e. ArrayList). After parsing the whole data you will get the all the vechile object in your collection(ArrayList).

Comment: Did you get solution of your problem ?